# scipy curve_fit strange result

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a distribution with scipy's curve_fit. I tried to fit a one component exponential function which resulted in an almost straight line (see figure). I also tried a two component exponential fit which seemed to work nicely. Two components just means that a part of the equation repeats with different input parameters. Anyway, here is the one component fit function:

```
def Exponential(Z,w0,z0,Z0):
    z = Z - Z0
    termB = (newsigma**2 + z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*newsigma*z0)
    termA = (newsigma**2 - z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*newsigma*z0)
    return w0/2.0 * numpy.exp(-(z**2 / (2.0*newsigma**2))) * (numpy.exp(termA**2)*erfc(termA) + numpy.exp(termB**2)*erfc(termB))
```

and the fitting is done with

```
fitexp = curve_fit(Exponential,newx,y2)
```

Then I tried something, just to try it out. I took two parameters of the two component fit, but did not use them in the calculation.

```
def ExponentialNew(Z,w0,z0,w1,z1,Z0):
    z = Z - Z0
    termB = (newsigma**2 + z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*newsigma*z0)
    termA = (newsigma**2 - z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*newsigma*z0)
    return w0/2.0 * numpy.exp(-(z**2 / (2.0*newsigma**2))) * (numpy.exp(termA**2)*erfc(termA) + numpy.exp(termB**2)*erfc(termB))
```

And suddenly this works.

[image]

Now, my quation is. WHY? As you can see, there is absolutely no difference in the calculation of the fit. It just gets two extra variables that are not used. Should this not get the same result?

@Andras_Deak
An actual example:

```
from scipy.special import erfc
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#setup data
x = [-58.,-54.,-50.,-46.,-42.,-38.,-34.,-30.,-26.,-22.,-18.,-14.,-10.,-6.,-2.,2.,6.,10.,14.,18.,22.,26.,30.,34.,38.,42.,46.,50.,54.,58.]
y = [23.06763817, 16.89802085, 17.83258379, 16.63446237, 13.81878965, 12.97965839, 14.30451789, 16.98288216, 22.26811491, 28.56756908, 33.06990344, 38.59842098, 54.19860393, 86.37381604, 137.47253315, 199.49724512, 238.66047662, 219.89405445, 160.68820199, 103.88901303, 65.92405727, 43.84596266, 31.5395342, 25.9610156, 22.71683709, 18.06740651, 13.85362374, 11.12867065, 10.36502799, 11.31855619]
y_err = [17.9823065, 4.13684885, 1.66490726, 2.4109372, 2.93359141, 1.9701747, 3.19214881,  3.65593012, 2.89089074, 3.58922121, 4.25505348, 4.72728874, 6.77736567, 11.3888196, 21.87771722, 39.0087495, 56.6910311, 51.7592369, 26.39750958, 10.62678862, 7.85893395, 8.11741621, 7.91731416, 7.07739132, 5.41818744, 6.11286843, 8.27070757, 7.85323065, 4.26885499, 0.9047867]

#function to fit
def Exponential2(Z, w0, z0, w1, z1, Z0):
    z = Z - Z0
    s = 3.98098937586
    a = z**2 / (2.0*s**2)
    b = (s**2 + z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*s*z0)
    c = (s**2 - z*z0) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*s*z0)
    d = (s**2 + z*z1) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*s*z1)
    e = (s**2 - z*z1) / (numpy.sqrt(2.0)*s*z1)
    return w0/2.0 * numpy.exp(-a) * (numpy.exp(c**2)*erfc(c) + numpy.exp(b**2)*erfc(b)) + w1/2.0 * numpy.exp(-a) * (numpy.exp(e**2)*erfc(e) + numpy.exp(d**2)*erfc(d))


#derive and set initial guess
ymaxpos = x[numpy.where(y==numpy.max(y))[0]]
p0_2 = [numpy.max(y),5,numpy.max(y)/2.0,20,ymaxpos]

#fit
fitexp2 = curve_fit(Exponential2,x,y,p0=p0_2,sigma=y_err)

#get results
w0err = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(fitexp2[1]))[0]
z0err = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(fitexp2[1]))[1]
w1err = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(fitexp2[1]))[2]
z1err = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(fitexp2[1]))[3]
w0 = fitexp2[0][0]
z0 = fitexp2[0][1]
w1 = fitexp2[0][2]
z1 = fitexp2[0][3]
Z0 = fitexp2[0][4]
#new x array for smoother curve
smoothx = numpy.arange(-58,59,0.1)
y2 = Exponential2(smoothx,w0,z0,w1,z1,Z0)

print 'Exponential 2: w0: '+str(w0.round(3))+' +/- '+str(w0err.round(3))+' \t z0: '+str(z0.round(3))+' +/- '+str(z0err.round(3))+' \t w1: '+str(w1.round(3))+' +/- '+str(w1err.round(3))+' \t\t z1: '+str(z1.round(3))+' +/- '+str(z1err.round(3))

#plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.errorbar(x,y,y_err,fmt='o',markersize=2,label='data')
ax.plot(smoothx,y2,label='fit',color='red')
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

As you can see, the plot does look good, but the returned value z1 is totaly unrealistic.

```
Exponential 2: w0: 312.608 +/- 36.764    z0: 8.263 +/- 1.158     w1: 12.689 +/- 9.138        z1: 1862257.883 +/- 45201809883.8
```

Comment: That's a pretty complicated model which I'm unfamiliar with. Does it not correspond to two humps? Your input data has one huge hump and one tiny one on the left, but it should be hard to find the latter one. My suspicion is that one of the humps in your model are far away from your data of interest, so essentially you're fitting a single hump to your data (hence the meaningless parameters). You could try fitting this one big hump, subtracting it from your data, then fitting another one to the remainder.

Comment: Actually, subtracting that main peak leaves behind a noise data set that doesn't seem to have clearly noticable features (within error bars). Are you sure that model is a good fit for your problem? It might be the case that part of the information is irrelevant/unnecessary (such as fitting the sum of two Gaussians to a single peak).

Comment: Yes. This is the distribution of light along the minor axis of a galaxy, which is supposed to be described by that model. I noticed, however, that if I get rid of the first 5 data points, the results are more credible. Maybe curve_fit can't handle this very first bump...

Comment: That is highly possible. If that bump is significantly independent from the big one, you should indeed ignore it in the fit. The problem is that the largest uncertainties are much larger than the expected noise on the left-side bump, even if said bump is above the baseline within error.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience [`curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) can sometimes act up and stick with the initial values for the parameters. I would suspect that in your case adding a few fake parameters changed the heuristics of how the relevant parameters are being initialized (although this contradicts the documentation's statement that with no initial values given, they all default to 1).

It helps a lot in obtaining reliable fits if you specify reasonable bounds and initial values for your fitting parameters (I mean the `p0` and `bounds` keywords). The fact that the default starting values should all be `1` suggests that for most use cases, the default won't cut it.

Comment: Thanks! But after a lot of testing, even setting bounds yields crappy results. For example without setting bounds, it would give me an w0 of 300 or so, but a z0 of 10e4, totally unreasonable. With bounds a w0 of around 300 and a z0 of 100, the same number as my bound for z0...

Comment: @Pythoneer yeah, that's pretty weird. Is there any chance you can put together a small sample of your data that reproduces the issue? I could also try playing around with it to see what might be wrong.

Comment: Sure. My xaxis is [-58. -54. -50. -46. -42. -38. -34. -30. -26. -22. -18. -14. -10.  -6.  -2.
   2.   6.  10.  14.  18.  22.  26.  30.  34.  38.  42.  46.  50.  54.  58.]

Comment: @Adras Deak, Sorry, I hit return and it postet immediatly, I hate this comment system. I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: @Pythoneer for one, you can edit comments within 5 minutes after posting. But this information belongs to the question anyway:)