# Scipy curve_fit gets stuck at bounds?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

(This is less a technical how-to question than trying to understand what's going on under the hood and whether what I'm encountering is a common issue. Please don't flag me!)

I've been running some nonlinear regressions with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and have been noticing that the optimization seems to get stuck at parameter bounds pretty often. For context, I've done a fair bit of nonlinear optimization with other software though I'm not expert at what goes into the algorithms; this is my first time using `scipy` for it, and it's just... getting stuck a *lot* more than I would expect.

A example of a function I'm feeding into `curve_fit` - here `t` and `dn` are various data series, length ~100-150:

```
def dynamic(exogs, alpha_0, delta, theta, beta):
    t, dn = exogs
    alpha_f = alpha_0 * delta
    return np.log(beta) - (alpha_0 + (1 - np.exp(-t/theta)) * (alpha_f - alpha_0)) * dn

non_bds = ([1e-02, 0.1, 5, 0], 
           [1e02, 10, 1e03, 10])

fit_non = curve_fit(dynamic, [df['t'], df['dn']], Y, bounds=non_bds, loss='huber', max_nfev=1e06)
```

In this case, `delta` is getting stuck at bounds (0.1 or 10) about 90% of the time, and `theta` at bounds about 50% of the time, neither of which I expect.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008017/scipy-curve-fit-strange-result) where it seems `curve_fit` does sometimes behave weirdly, so am wondering - is it common for the optimizer for `curve_fit` to get stuck at bounds? Is this a known issue, and are there any good ways to address it either by tweaking any of the settings or with other workarounds?

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing a similar problem. Did you find any way to troubleshoot this?